# DB2 Express-C 11.1 connection problem Windows 11

Tags: db2, amd-processor, windows-11, db2-express-c

I'm trying to connect to DB2 Express-C 11.1 on Windows 11 from Docker container.
I`m running just 2 commands inside container with DB (on the screen) and after second one it just hanging endlessly.

```
db2 'CREATE DATABASE MYAPP2 AUTOMATIC STORAGE YES USING CODESET UTF-8 TERRITORY PL COLLATE USING UCA400_NO'
db2 connect to myapp2 user db2inst1 using db2inst1-pwd
```

I have AMD Ryzen 7 5800H processor with Radeon Graphics 3.20 GHz, 16 GB RAM, Windows 11 Pro x64 v. 21H2

Comment: Where is your Db2, all in the container or outside? Which user is executing the db2 command? There should be logs. Add details to the question

Comment: My DB2 is fully in containers, user is db2inst1. Could you tell which exactly logs do you need? About DB2 start, database creation, connection, etc.? Cause db2diag.log contains too many of them

Comment: There are some error messages that i have: 
`MESSAGE : Detected kernel config that is incompatible with DB2 NUMA support.` , 
`MESSAGE : ECF=0x900001BF=-1879047745=ECF_GENREG_OPEN_INPUT_FILE_FAILED Failed to open the input registry CALLED  : DB2 Common, OSSe, OSSHFile::open RETCODE : ECF=0x9000001A=-1879048166=ECF_FILE_DOESNT_EXIST File doesn't exist`  ,
`MESSAGE : ECF=0x90000262=-1879047582=ECF_GENREG_INVALID_GLOB_REG_HANDLE The Global Registry handle is invalid` ,
`MESSAGE : Table type error forcing LOAD to quit , -3304, (nil), Detected in file:sqlulval.C, Line:2398`